# How to upload an iPhone app to app store?

Tags: ios, app-store

Can I upload an iPhone app to appstore by using team developer admin account?

I am a member of a iOS team of my client. My client has made me as admin in member center. I can now able to create certificates and provisional profiles. Now, I have an app which needs to be uploaded into the App Store. As I have admin rights in member center, can I be able to upload apps on his behalf?

If there is any way, please tell me the way step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload app on app store, only team agent can this.
If you upload, you use your agent apple id.
Thanks.